# using excluse option in Oracle Scheduler for weekly schedule

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, scheduler

We have configured our scheduler to run on weekly basis on evert monday but as a requirement, we would like to skip this scheduler for specific date of months. like i dont want to run this for 15May2015, 16June2015 etc.

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute( name => '"SCHEMA"."NAME"', attribute => 'repeat_interval', value => 'FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MON;BYHOUR=13;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0');
END; 
/
```

I have checked with scheduler argument and can see using EXCLUSE argument we can achieve that but every time I try its giving me compilation error.

Could someone pls help.

Comment: For evaluation you can use also this procedure: [DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#i1009923)

Answer (score 0):

you have to define first another schedule for the excluded days. If there's no real repeating pattern between them, you have to define a schedule for each excluded day.  Something like this:

```
BEGIN

    -- define a schedule for May 15th
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
        repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0515',     
        comments         => 'Exclude May 15th',
        schedule_name    => '"May15th"'
    ); 

    -- define a schedule for June 16th
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
        repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0616',     
        comments         => 'Exclude June 16th',
        schedule_name    => '"June16th"'
    );

    -- note the EXCLUDE in the value parameter
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute( 
        name => '"SCHEMA"."NAME"', 
        attribute => 'repeat_interval', 
        value => 'FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MON;BYHOUR=13;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0;EXCLUDE=May15th,Jun16th;'
    );
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can we have all those excluded dates as part of one schedule. In my case, we have 15 such dates and we dont have to have 15 scheduler for that. Pls advise.

Comment: if there is any repeating relationship between the 15 days (e.g. they occur every 30 days, or every first Saturday in a month) you can define a single schedule for all of them, putting the appropriate repeating interval. If the dates are "random", then you have to define 15 schedules :( Unfortunately there's no simpler way.

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is to move this logic on the process that's being executed by the scheduler. For example if the scheduler executes a procedure, you can check inside that procedure if sysdate is in a list of predefined dates (you can store them in a lookup table) and execute the rest of the package only if the sysdate is not one of the exclusded ones.

Comment: Its not working for me. Keep on giving this error.ORA-27412: repeat interval or calendar contains invalid identifier: "SOA_SOAINFRA"."MAY15TH"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 4478
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 2862

Comment: If you use SOA_SOAINFRA."MAY15TH" make sure you have also defined the May15th schedule in uppercase.

Comment: You can combine schedules like this: `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE('ScheduleExcludes', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;INTERSECT=May15th,Jun16th');`

Comment: All- I have tried configuring single scheduler like     FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0508,0509,0510,0511,0513 and used that as part of DB job. Its working fine. So I dont think so we have to create different scheduler for diff dates. in one scheduler, we can specify all dates and use it.